# Javascript ternary operator with?

Tags: javascript

I saw this in a line of code for some javascript I inherited.

What does this mean?

msg is just an object. I am somewhat confused by the !!. Not sure why anyone would put this condition there

(!!msg ? true : false)

Comment: Apparently you did not even take the time to search...

Comment: Hope fully this link help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: !!msg == Boolean(msg)

Comment: replace with `!!msg`, `Boolean(msg)`, or just `msg` and it'll be fine. the ternary is entirely unnecessary. (just `msg` won't be enough if you NEED a boolean)